# R Plotting list of ggplots onto multiple pages

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list of ggplots created from:

```
files_list <- list.files("file_directory")
sani_list <- list()

for (file in files_list){
  df <- fread(paste0("file_directory,file))
  
  cnames <- colnames(df[,4:10])
  df$sex_id <- as.factor(df$sex_id)
  
  
  for (i in cnames){
    if (i == "sani_value"){
      plot <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=i, y=df$incidence, color=df$sex_id)) +
        geom_point()+geom_smooth(method='loess', size=0.25)
      sani_list <- c(sani_list,grob(plot))
    }
  }
}
```

There is a total of 195 ggplots created and stored in a list. What is the best way these over multiple pages, ie. - 13 plots over 5 pages? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of two plots that are dumped into separate pages of pdf.

```
library(tidyverse); library(grid)

p <- ggplot(iris %>% filter(Species == "setosa"), aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) + geom_point()
q <- ggplot(iris %>% filter(Species == "versicolor"), aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) + geom_point()

fig_list <- list()
fig_list <- c(fig_list, grob(p))
fig_list <- c(fig_list, grob(q))

pdf("test.pdf")
fig_list
dev.off()
```

Quite hard to replicated your issue, but hope that this example will help you out.